# Ideals generated by primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

I understand that since $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, all subgroups (and in particular all ideals) of $\mathbb{Z}$ are also cyclic and thusly generated by a single element, hence $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID.

The ideal $(2,3)$ is clearly equivalent to $(1)$, since $$3-2=1\implies1\in(2,3)\implies\mathbb{Z}=(1)\subseteq(2,3)\implies(1)=(2,3).$$ Is there a similarly easy proof that for primes $p_0>p_1>1$, there exists another prime $p_2\geq1$  such that $$(p_0,p_1)=(p_2)?$$ As a stronger followup, is $$(p_0,p_1)=(1)$$ for all primes $p_0,p_1>1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for $\mathbb{Z}$, $(a,b)=(\gcd(a,b))$. If $p\ne q$ are primes of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\gcd(p,q)=1$, so $(p,q)=(1)$.

This follows from the fact that for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $\gcd(a,b)=ax+by$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.